# SpreadJS Using the import feature to load an xls from the server that contains pivot tables

Tags: javascript

I have attempted to import an xlsx file using the sample import site that has a pivot table in it and it imports correctly but the number formatting is not correct in all cells.
If you export the imported file back to xlsx and save it on your desktop it will have the correct formatting?
I am not sure why this occurs.
Is this supported?

Answer (score 0):

seems spreadjs not support pivot table yet. you may goto wijmo web site and ask this in the community forum: http://wijmo.com/forums/community/